# Bootstrap dropdown menu - not working on subpage

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using bootstrap and created a dropdown menu. The main item is a link that works on the homepage but not on the subpage.

Here's my code:

```html
<li>
  <a href="/preview/#design-centre" class="dropdown-toggle scroll" 
     data-toggle="dropdown" data-hover="dropdown">
    Design Centre <i class="fa fa-angle-down"></i>
  </a>
  <ul class="menulist dropdown-menu">
    <li><a href="/preview/#design-centre">Overview</a></li>
    <li><a href="/preview/design-centre.php?action=video-testimonials">Video Testimonials</a></li>
    <li><a href="/preview/design-centre.php?action=meet-the-team">Meet The Team</a></li>
    <li><a href="/preview/design-centre.php?action=faq">FAQ</a></li>
    <li><a href="/preview/design-centre.php?action=contact-us">Contact Us</a></li>
  </ul>
</li>
```

When I click on Design Centre, it does not do anything on a subpage, but on a homepage it does, all other links that are in the navigation but are not dropdown menus work.

Comment: It is because of homepage Url link. # stops your navigation. It's better if you can implement cation for home page also.

Comment: most of the animated bits with bootstrap are javascript driven, ill be willing to bet that's where the problem lies.

Comment: Can you add enough code to reproduce your problem?

Answer (score 2):

This *should* work fine.  What you're trying to do has nothing to do with Bootstrap, per se, and is merely trying to use anchor links to navigate both within a document and also to fragments of another document.  This is just standard HTML markup.

The [fragment identifier](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/intro/intro.html#fragment-uri) is the portion of the URI that:

> refers to a location within a resource

As long as those links work individually, they should work in your code.

Some things that might mess it up:

- If you're using relative URLS, then the address will change based on where in the navigation you are.  Since you are starting your href address with a slash, this does not appear to be the case.
- You can try converting the following line:

  ```
  <li><a href="/preview/#design-centre">Overview</a></li>
  ```

  To this (assuming your root page is *`index.html`*):

  ```
  <li><a href="/preview/index.html#design-centre">Overview</a></li>
  ```

  Sometimes the page can be inferred by your asset pipeline, but it's generally better to be explicit.

#### [Here's a working example in plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/FVaHRGX8XoMHMHYjdwGS?p=preview)

[**And here's a runnable version**](http://run.plnkr.co/plunks/FVaHRGX8XoMHMHYjdwGS/index.html) that includes a main page and subpage with working fragments

Beyond that, we'd need more info to diagnose.  If it still doesn't work, try to fork the plunker and add any changes that visibly show the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Please check if in the source code of the page where it's not working you have an element with `id="design-centre"` (probably an anchor `<a>`, often also used in conjunction with the `name` attribute). There probably will be none, but the homepage will have it. It's meant to be used as a kind of in-page navigation. Clicking a link that has a hash (`#`) at the end triggers the browser to look for an element with a corresponding `id`, and scroll the viewport so it's right on top.

Answer (score 0):

try this [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/5fcm126a/)

```
<li class="dropdown">
        <a href="/preview/#design-centre" class="dropdown-toggle disabled" 
     data-toggle="dropdown" data-hover="dropdown">
    Design Centre <i class="fa fa-angle-down"></i>
  </a>
  <ul class="menulist dropdown-menu" role="menu">
    <li><a href="/preview/#design-centre">Overview</a></li>  
  </ul>
 </li>
```

Answer (score 0):

As this is a dropdown. I don't think you need to add href to the anchor tag.

You can just keep a # inside the href.

This is the updated code,

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<ul style="position:relative">
<li>
  <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle scroll" 
     data-toggle="dropdown" data-hover="dropdown">
    Design Centre <i class="fa fa-angle-down"></i>
  </a>
  <ul class="menulist dropdown-menu">
    <li><a href="/preview/#design-centre">Overview</a></li>
    <li><a href="/preview/design-centre.php?action=video-testimonials">Video Testimonials</a></li>
    <li><a href="/preview/design-centre.php?action=meet-the-team">Meet The Team</a></li>
    <li><a href="/preview/design-centre.php?action=faq">FAQ</a></li>
    <li><a href="/preview/design-centre.php?action=contact-us">Contact Us</a></li>
  </ul>
</li></ul>
```

Comment: Avijit, if you're going to add code as a runnable snippet, please include all of the required libraries so that it actual runs.  For Bootstrap, you can click on the [tag info](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/twitter-bootstrap/info) to see a list of html to add to your snippet. Otherwise, you can just omit the `<!-- snippet` sections to include plain old syntax highlighted code the old fashioned way.

Comment: thanks for reminding it. I added the required libraries @KyleMit