# Bootstrap 5 dropdown menu working on parent but not on child pages

Tags: html, bootstrap-5

I'm new at Bootstrap. I'm trying to implement a dropdown menu for my website, and used [Bootstrap documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.1/components/dropdowns/) (5.1) to put up a working example.

Currently the dropdown menu is working as expected but only in the homepage. Here's the code I'm using:

```
<head>
...
...
    <link href="https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
</head>
```

```
<body>
...
...
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark fixed-top bg-dark" >
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <a href="{{.Site.BaseURL}}" class="navbar-brand">
            <img src="{{.Site.BaseURL}}{{ .Site.Params.site_logo }}" alt="" width="70%" height="auto"  class="d-inline-block align-text-top"></a>
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggler" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarCollapse">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span></button>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse justify-content-between" id="navbarCollapse">
                <div class="navbar-nav ms-auto">
                    <a href="{{.Site.BaseURL}}cursos" class="nav-item nav-link">Cursos</a>
                    <a href="{{.Site.BaseURL}}consultoria" class="nav-item nav-link">Consultoría</a>
                    <div class="nav-item dropdown">
                        <a href="#" class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" data-bs-toggle="dropdown">Recursos</a>
                        <div class="dropdown-menu">
                            <a href="{{.Site.BaseURL}}contacto" class="dropdown-item">Contacto</a>
                            <a href="{{.Site.BaseURL}}blog" class="dropdown-item">Blog</a>
                            <a href="{{.Site.BaseURL}}descargas" class="dropdown-item">Descargas</a>
                            <a href="{{.Site.BaseURL}}acerca-de" class="dropdown-item">Acerca de</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <a href="#" class="btn btn-outline-light" role="button">Suscribirse</a>
                </div>
            </div>
    </div>
</nav>

...
</body>
```

The dropdown Menu is named `Recursos` and in the homepage it works as expected, i.e. the menu items appear when clicking on the dropdown:

[image]

However, when I navigate to a subpage the dropdown menu stops working, and nothing happens when i click on it. So the problem lies here:

```
<a href="#" class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" data-bs-toggle="dropdown">Recursos</a>
```

I've noticed that in the homepage, the link points to `homepage/#` when hovering over the dropdown menu, and it works like a charm. However, for sub-pages the link automatically gets updated and points to the URL of the corresponding subpage (for example to `homepage/blog/#` or `homepage/about/#`) and then it stops working.

How can I prevent Bootstrap from updating the dropdown's link?

I've tried also leaving empty the `href` field when creating the dropdown component (`href=""`) and the problem persists.

I've also tried the solutions proposed in a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29306955/bootstrap-dropdown-menu-not-working-on-subpage), to no avail.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Solved it!

I was calling a local version of `bootstrap.bundle.min.js`:

```
<script src="js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
```

but forgot to include `/` at the beginning of the path, and thus when rendering the subpage the .js file was not found.

Once corrected:

```
<script src="/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
```

everything worked as expected!